# What is the code for the elevator in FNAF Sister Location?

Tags: fnaf-sister-location

I was playing Five Nights At Freddy's Sister Location when I found a little number pad in the elevator. I tried several number sequences (1983, 1987, 1234, 2320245) but none of them worked. If anyone knows the number sequence that'd be very useful to me.

Comment: Have you tried [this number](https://www.reddit.com/r/fivenightsatfreddys/comments/56jhl9/keypad_in_elevatorcould_that_lead_to_something/d8jsx0e)? Or any of the numbers listed [here](http://www.oneangrygamer.net/2016/10/five-nights-at-freddys-sister-location-walkthrough/13629/)?

Comment: Based on things that people have found when data-mining, it seems like this keypad is linked to an alternate "elevator ending," but no one has figured out how to get to it at this time.

Comment: @Vemonus ok, thank you, though why did you vote the question down?

Comment: I didn't. You don't have 1k rep to see the aggregate votes, so I'll tell you. I voted up, but two others voted down. I'm honestly not sure what is wrong with your question, personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm late, but if you type 1983 in the keypad to the left of the Baby poster you will turn on the monitors in the secret room permanently.

Answer (score -3):

its 1738 no lie then its a bunch of stuff to get exotic butters aswell